# Plugins for net-data to show creation date

Tags: plugins, grafana, monitor, grafana-api, netdata

I just got a project to, where the user wants to add the following feature in the net-data monitoring for the virtual machines.

1. creation date
2. uptime
3. internal ip
4. external ip

Comment: Can you describe your use case a little bit more as well as the tools you are trying to use? Netdata supports process uptime, network interface monitoring, and vCenter server monitoring, for example.